# Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, h2

I'm trying to use h2 database and microservices. But when i run the application it doesn't run, it is showing errors.
I have eureka server and a product microservice. In product microservice i have used h2database. it is showing errors.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception 
     is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'h2Console' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via 
factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 
'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' 
defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean 
 instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver  

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw 
exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean 
instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver  

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
```

The below is my dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The below is my application.properties file of Product microservice

```
server.port=8082

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.datasource.name=SunHome

#H2 settings
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb  
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver  
spring.datasource.username=sa  
springspring.datasource.password=  
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Please help me solve this errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check applcation.properties for "strange" characters
Configuration should be right.